# Probability measure over the irrationals

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am taking my first steps into measure theory, so I apologize in advance if my question is too basic or naive.

Consider the set of the irrationals, $\Omega=\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$. There exists any probability measure on $(\Omega, 2^\Omega)$? If so, can you give me an explicit definition of such probability measure?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there are lots of probability measures. Here's one:

Assign measure $1$ to any subset $A$ that contains the number $\pi$, and measure $0$ otherwise.

It's not too hard to check that this is an actual measure. It's not a very interesting one, I grant you, but it satisfies all the axioms.

Comment: Rather easy actually :P I was thinking of something "fancier", but your answer clearly fulfills all the requirements.